# Building jar file with ant

Tags: java, build, ant

I am trying to create a jar file from custom code. I have already installed ant and it works fine but the build process fails everytime when I start it in the shell. Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong? I have attached a screenshot of my shell and my custom code.

[Screenshot Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9iIS.jpg)

My Code: https://ufile.io/ydt0s

Thanks

Comment: paste the images in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have git: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git
Try that